# Document must be a valid JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this script:

```
let offersToUpdate = [];
let offersToRemove = [];

while (await cursor.hasNext()) {

      let offer = await cursor.next();
      let product = await db.collection('products').findOne({_id: offer.product._id});

      if (product == null) {
        offersToRemove.push(offer._id);
      } else {
        offersToUpdate.push(offer._id);
      }
  }

  await db.collection('offers').update({_id: {$in: offersToUpdate}});
  await db.collection('offers').remove({_id: {$in: offersToRemove}});
```

When I execute it I have this error:

```
document must be a valid JavaScript object
```

Do you have any idea why I have it?

Thanks!

Comment: [`.update()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) needs at least two parameters, you're missing what the update is supposed to do. is it even needed? you remove whatever you'd update in the next line

Comment: Ha ok thanks! But I am not removing what I am updating. Different varaibles ;)

Answer (score 0):

The update method requires two parameters, one filter parameter and another update parameter. As per the code you have only provided one parameter, pls refer to [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding a code example.